# PHP MSSQL issue with accented characters

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having issues with accented characters and encoding while using MSSQL and PHP - we have a table that contains characters such as é - when we display that using PHP we get squares - �.

I've tried setting the charset as UTF-8, using 'SET NAMES UTF-8', also tried removing those settings... I cannot get it working!

Interestingly, if I run 'echo mb_detect_encoding($VarWithAccentedChars);'

it returns UTF-8...

Any ideas on where i'm going wrong?!

As a note, if I look at the table in SSMS I can view the data correctly..

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your HTML output is also UTF-8.

Comment: I've already tried <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; Charset=UTF-8"; /> - but no luck. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: I never use MSSQL, but in MySQL I would also have to make sure that the column in the table is UTF-8. So there are several points: 1. table definition, transport layer(s) (SET NAMES), and output, which all need to be UTF-8. And, of course, the other way around as well, when you input a string into the database.

Comment: Table definition (according to SSMS) is Latin1_General_CS_AS
SET NAMES UTF-8 is part of the SQL connection
Output (Meta Tags) are defined as per my previous post

Still no luck :( Could it be related to the SQL Server being 'Latin1_General_CS_AS' - Can I set the Names and Meta tags to be an equivalent of that?

Comment: Got it! used iso-8859-1 as an alternative and it's now working :)